# EXTJs Action Column icon

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I want the icon to change from accept to delete when it is clicked on.
Set the `iconflag = 1` because on page load I want the accept icon to be seen.

The code below doesn't satisfy the expectation

```
{

    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    width: 30,
    items: [{
        flex: 1,
        tooltip: 'Click to expand',
        icon: iconflag == '1' ? "shared/icons/fam/accept.gif" : "shared/icons/fam/delete.gif",
        getClass: this.getActionClass,
        handler: function() {
            if (iconflag == '1') {
                iconflag = '0';
            } else if (iconflag == '0') {
                iconflag = '1';
            }
            alert(iconflag);
        }
    }]

},
```

Using EXTJs 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your handler function, `iconflag` is a local variable that loses its value outside the handler function. Where you use iconflag outside the handler function, it is evaluated only ONCE, before you click on the icon.

What you want to do is store your variable in a place that automatically forces the grid to update. Which is why you want to store the iconflag on the records in the store.

Add to your model another field:

```
{
    name: 'iconflag',
    type: 'bool',
    defaultValue: false,
    persist: false
}
```

Move the icons into CSS:

```
Ext.util.CSS.createStyleSheet([
    '.iconflag-accept {',
    '     background-image: url(\'shared/icons/fam/accept.gif\')',
    '}',
    '.iconflag-delete {'
    '    background-image: url(\'shared/icons/fam/delete.gif\')',
    '}'
].join(''));
```

Update the column to use the field:

```
dataIndex: 'iconflag',
getClass: function(iconflag) {
    if(iconflag) return 'iconflag-delete';
    else return 'iconflag-accept';
},
handler: function(view, colindex, rowindex, item, e, record) {
    record.set('iconflag', !record.get('iconflag'));
}
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/205l

Comment: Since every grid row you want to show is based on a store record, the store is your best bet. Of course there are other ways; they are just around 3 to 20 times more code, which will possibly have to be reworked during framework upgrades, and which won't be easy to understand for fellow programmers. The code provided is standard-issue ExtJS code that works with every ExtJS version between 4.2.0 and 6.5-classic, and presumably also with future versions.